# Локальный GPS для определения положения объекта в ограниченном пространстве и вертикальная трилатерация

Tags: gps, обработка-сигналов

Я знаю как работает gps, методом измерения времени между приемом сигнала и синхронизацией со спутниками.

Возможно ли реализовать данную схему, заменив спутники на локальные трансмиттеры радио-сигнала, и приемником сделать объект-ресивер для измерения фактического положения в ограниченном пространстве?

К примеру это можно было бы использовать в системах vr, расположив трансмиттеры по концам комнаты и прикрепив ресивер к контроллеру, избежав оптического измерения маркеров камерами.

Добавлено: существует ли возможность вертикальной радио трилатерации для нахождения высоты объекта?

Comment: конечно, можно. Внутри треугольника, в вершинах которого расположены радиопередатчики и приёмники, вы можете определить координату объекта

Comment: Я бы хотел еще переформулировать свой вопрос
Возможно ли это сделать в условиях 3д отслеживания, а не по плоскости XY. Возможно ли делать радио трилатерацию для нахождения высоты расположения объекта на ограниченном пространстве?

Comment: Можно, но для получения трёх координат нужен не треугольник, а тетраэдр - 4 трансмиттера, не лежащие в одной плоскости